# .htaccess RewriteRule sub.subdomain.domain.com => subdomain.domain.com/sub

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite

Есть субдомен - **subdomain.domain.com**

Хочу сделать, что бы по такому адресу - **sub.subdomain.domain.com** открывалась папка **subdomain.domain.com/sub**

**sub** - это папка, которая доступна по адресу - **subdomain.domain.com/sub**

Можно ли такое сделать? без создание субдомена для уже существующего субдомена.

В корне субдомена -  **subdomain.domain.com**, в файле: **.htaccess** я написал:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/$1 [L]
```

Мне выдает такую ошибку: 
*Не удается найти DNS-адрес сервера sub.subdomain.domain.com.*

Кто знает как помочь, буду благодарен :-)